# Power BI Impossible to handle an error in dataset scheduled refresh

Tags: powerbi, dataset, refresh

I am facing a problem with no response for now in Microsoft Power BI docs and different forums.
I have a Power BI dataset scheduled refresh which it's not working and the showing message error is **"Unable to connect to the data source undefined"**

The dataset is connected to an SQL database hosted in a server in which is correctly installed an On-premises Gateway.
The connections are to the data sources are set correctly.

When the schedule refresh runs it fails every time, when we try to refresh manually it works!

Does someone has faced this issue and how it can be handle?

Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

When the refresh fails is the server online? I would also check to make sure to double check the credentials to the database in the gateway settings in Power Bi service.

Comment: When the refresh is online yes. The dataset filled thanks to jobs which execute SSIS packages.
I have already checked the credentials.
Have you ever been confronted by this error

Comment: UPDATE : It seems that was an issue raised by different conflicts with jobs running in the same time in the same server.
So I supposed that the connection was unreachable because of an out-memory.